# Smart pointers with a library written in C

Tags: c++, opencv, smart-pointers, raii

I'm using C++ with the OpenCV library, which is a library image-processing although that's not relevant for this question. Currently I have a design decision to make.

OpenCV, being a C library, has its data structures (such as CvMat) declared as structs. To create them, you use functions like cvCreateMat, and to release them, you use functions like cvReleaseMat. Being a C++ programmer, I created a special `cv_scoped` class which would automatically call cvReleaseMat when it went out of scope (like `boost::scoped_ptr`).

What I'm realising now is that I wish I could use `auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr` in cases as well. I just feel that writing code for my own `cv_auto_ptr` and `cv_shared_ptr` classes would be a bad idea, not to mention a waste of time. So I've been looking for solutions, and I've come up with three possibilities.

**First**, I could use the cv_scoped class I've already made. I'd rename it to `cv_ptr` and then use smart pointers like so: `std::auto_ptr<cv_ptr>`. The annoying thing about this though is, I'd always have to dereference twice:

```
std::auto_ptr<cv_ptr> matrix(cv_ptr(cvCreateMat(320, 240, CV_32FC3)));
cvPow(matrix.get()->get()); // one get for the auto_ptr, one for the cv_ptr
```

I know it looks like I could declare an implicit conversion, but I couldn't actually - most of OpenCV's functions have the parameter void* - so no implicit conversion would be called. I would really like a way of doing this where I didn't have to do the double dereference.

**Second**, I could somehow override `operator delete`. I don't want to override the global operator delete because I'd only want this to apply to CvMat (and a few other) types. However, I can't change the library, so I can't add `operator delete` to the CvMat struct. So I don't know how this would work.

**Third**, I could just rewrite my own `auto_ptr`, `scoped_ptr`, and `shared_ptr`. They're not large classes so it wouldn't be too difficult, but I just feel like this is bad design. If I were to do this, I would probably do something along these lines:

```
class cv_auto_ptr {
public:
  cv_auto_ptr();
  ~cv_auto_ptr();

  // each method would just be a proxy for the smart pointer
  CvMat* get() { return this->matrix_.get()->get(); }
  // all the other operators/methods in auto_ptr would be the same, you get the idea

private:
  auto_ptr<cv_ptr> matrix_; // cv_ptr deletes CvMat properly
}
```

What would you do in my situation? Please help me figure this one out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto_ptr are really designed for RAII on C++ class with constructs/destructors you are pushing their uses here to things they probably should not be used for (but can).

Anyway don'y you want to be able to use your C++ object as if it was a normal stack variable without dynamically allocating each time?

The standard solution to your problem is to create a wrapper with constructor/destructor.
But to make it usable by the C functions just add an internal cast operator so it auto-magically converts itself back to the C object when passed to a C function

Write a wrapper class.

```
class Mat
{
    CvMat* impl;
    public:
        Mat(/* Constructor  Arguments */)
        {
            impl = cvCreateMat(/* BLAH */);
        }
        ~Mat()
        {
            cvReleaseMat(impl);
        }
        operator CvMat*()
        {   // Cast opertator. Convert your C++ wrapper object into C object
            // when you use it with all those C functions that come with the
            // library.

            return impl;
        }
};

void Plop(CvMat* x)
{   // Some C function dealing with CvMat
}

int main()
{                            // Don't need to dynamically allocate
    Mat                  m;  // Just create on the stack.
    Plop(m);                 // Call Plop directly

    std::auto_ptr<Mat>   mP(new Mat);
    Plop(*mP);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this for about 15 minutes and I think you might be onto the best solution here. The differences from this and the other solutions are subtle yet very important. I'm going to think about it a bit longer though before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 6):

One approach that you could consider is to used the fact that `std::tr1::shared_ptr` has the functionality to provide a custom deleter. I have no familiarity with OpenCV so I'm inferring from what you've written.

```
struct CvMatDeleter
{
    void operator( CvMat* p ) { cvReleaseMat( p ) ; }
};

void test()
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr< CvMat > pMat( cvCreateMat(320, 240, CV_32FC3), CvMatDeleter() );
    // . . .
}
```

Because the deleter is store in the shared pointer you can just use it as normal and when the shared raw pointer finally needs to be deleted, `cvReleaseMat` will be called as required. Note that `auto_ptr` and `scoped_ptr` are much lighter classes so don't have the functionality for custom deleters, but if you're prepared for the small overhead then `shared_ptr` can be used in their place.

Comment: Wow that sounds like exactly what I need, for the shared_ptr at least. Thanks!

Comment: hmm why the functor? why not pass cvReleaseMat as a deleter directly?

Comment: No real reason; habit I suppose. In some cases it can be slightly more efficient to use a functor as its body can be inlined at the point of use. In this case, I doubt it makes any difference at all.

Comment: right. can you elaborate on the functor being more efficient? I don't understand why it's easier to inline than a function pointer

Comment: Basically for a function pointer, its type only encapsulates its signature, but a functor's type encapsulates its behaviour as well. At compile time, if you are a function that is given a function pointer, you have to call it to effect its behaviour, whereas a functor's operator() may be known.

Comment: In OpenCV's case, the functor object is needed anyway because cvReleaseMat is `void cvReleaseMat(CvMat** p)` (it sets the pointer to NULL after deleting)

Answer (score 3):

If all you care about is exception safety, do this everytime you use matrixes:

```
void f() {
    try {
        CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat(320, 240, CV_32FC3));
        // ...
    } catch(...) {
        cvReleaseMat(mat);
        throw;
    }
    cvReleaseMat(mat);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want a **sane** solution, go the extra mile and write a full wrapper.

```
namespace cv {

class Mat {
public:
    enum Type { /* ... */ };
    Mat(int w, int h, Type type) {
        impl = cvCreateMat(w, h, intFromType(type));
    }

    ~Mat() {
        cvReleaseMat(impl);
    }

    void pow() { // wrap all operations
        cvPow(impl);
    }

private:
    CvMat* impl;
};

}
```

Going the middle way, using a hodge podge of generic smart pointers and "cv_ptrs" sounds like a recipe for headaches and an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I see your point but I think I would probably go for my own smart pointers over this. I think because there are so many different functions and types, I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel rewriting their signatures. Thanks though!